# Error in getting JSON value

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is my server side output

```
[{"Id":"1","Username":"kamesh","Password":"kamesh","Email":"kameeshwaran.han@gmail.co","Employeeid":"hankamesh","Phonenumber":""}]
```

Now i am trying to access this Username and Password from my localhost using myhtml file.
**mylocal.html**

```
$.ajax({
            url:"XXXX?callback=?",
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',                
            success:function(output){
            alert("working");
                    $.each(output,function(key,value){
                        $('#result').append('<p>Row '+key+' : UserName '+value.Username+'Password'+value.Password+'</p><br>');
                    });
            }
        });         
      });
```

I do not know whether it is correct or not. can anyone guide me please ..thanks in advance

Comment: @Ehswer..What is the error your are getting?

Comment: nothing is displaying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add proper header in server side, sometimes it's create issue..
PHP

```
header("Content-type: text/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

And in jQuery, please make sure the response in json object... if response may be string not an object then please parse response in json object, 
There no need $.each loop, please try this
please see blow

```
$.ajax({
            url:"XXXX?callback=?",
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',                
            success:function(output){
               var response_obj = {};
               try {
                 response_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(output)[0];
              }catch(e){alert('error==>' + e);}
                    $('#result').append('<p>Row username : UserName'+response_obj.Username+'Password'+response_obj.Password+'</p><br>');

            }
        });         
      });
```

I hope, issue  would be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.each(json, function() {
          $.each(this, function(name, value) {
            console.log(Name+ '=' + Value);

          });
        });
```

Can you just verify whether this code is giving you any results..

Comment: Datatype is set to JSON so no parsing required

Comment: i already set dataType to json... same kind of code i tried before it was working that time now it is not working ... i dono why

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(output,function(key,value){
                        $('#result').append('<p>'+key+': '+value+'</p><br>');
                    });
```

to access specific fields

```
$('#result').append('<p> UserName:'+output.Username+'Password :'+output.Password+'</p><br>');
```

Comment: here how can i split Username alone?

Comment: you are iterating in $.each() to fecth all the key value pairs in the row

Comment: if you want to access only Username you dont need the $.each()